# Geodesic equation & Four-velocity

Tags: velocity, relativity, geodesics

I've been studying Kolb & Turner's "The Early Universe", and came across an equation that somehow I can't understand. Given the equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{u_0} \frac{d |\vec u|}{ds} + \frac{\dot a(t)}{a(t)}|\vec u| = 0
\end{equation}

They write:

\begin{equation}
\frac{|\dot{ \vec{u}}|}{|\vec u|} = -\frac{\dot a(t)}{a(t)}
\end{equation}

Stating that

\begin{equation}
u^0 \equiv \frac{dt}{ds}
\end{equation}

This last expression is quite simple, but I can't derive it... Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just plug $u_0= \frac{d t}{d s}$ into the first equation 
$$\frac{1}{u_0} \frac{d |\vec u|}{ds} + \frac{\dot a(t)}{a(t)}|\vec u| = \frac{d s}{d t} \frac{d |\vec u|}{ds} + \frac{\dot a(t)}{a(t)}|\vec u| = 0 0$$

Identify $ \frac{d s}{d t} \frac{d |\vec u|}{ds}= \frac{d |\vec u|}{dt}=\dot u(t)$ through chain rule and you are ready

Comment: No, what I don't understand is the last expression,

\begin{equation} u^0 = \frac{dt}{ds} \end{equation}

Not the replacement. But thanks!

Comment: I dont have the book but I would guess it is just the definiton of the zeroth four-velocity component

Comment: And in FLRW metric $u_0=u^0$

Comment: $u^0\equiv dt/ds$ is the definiton of the time component of the four velocity, that is why there is an "equivalent" sign not an "equal". It is the same as in special relativity.

Answer (score 0):

Well simply put, a metric can be written as
$$ ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$$

and if you rewrite it a little, it gives
$$1 = g_{\mu\nu}u^{\mu}u^{\nu} = u_{\nu}u^{\nu}$$
with Einstein summation implied.

Here we have defined $u^{\mu}$ and $u_{\mu}$ such that it equals $\frac{dx^{\mu}}{ds}$ and $\frac{dx_{\mu}}{ds}$ respectively where ${\mu}$ spans {0,1,2,3} in most cases. Denoting the zeroth index in {0,1,2,3} for time, while other three usually reserved exclusively for the spatial indexes (some authors identify the time index with the number 4 as in {1,2,3,4} rather than 0)

Thus we get the relation

$$u^0 = \frac{dt}{ds}$$